# Android AsyncTask Sockets

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a remote application for Android devices. The server will run on a pc and the client on a smartphone, both devices will need to be connected to the same network.
Right now I'm trying to write the client app and for the connection part I use sockets and ASyncTask.
On my app, I have a Fragment where I added 2 EditTexts(for IP Address and Port) and 1 Button(Connect).

As I mentioned, I'm using ASyncTask and here's the code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connect, container, false);

    IPAddress = view.findViewById(R.id.IPAddress);
    IPAddressInput = IPAddress.getText().toString();

    PortTCP = view.findViewById(R.id.PortTCP);
    PortTCPInput = PortTCP.getText().toString();
    connectPhoneTask = new ConnectPhoneTask();

    connectButton = view.findViewById(R.id.connectButton);

    View.OnClickListener connectListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            connectPhoneTask.execute();
        }
    };
    connectButton.setOnClickListener(connectListener);

    return view;
}

class ConnectPhoneTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        boolean result = true;
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(params[0]);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, Constants.SERVER_PORT);//Open socket on server IP and port
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("remotedroid", "Error while connecting", e);
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        isConnected = result;
        Toast.makeText(context, isConnected ? "Connected to server!" : "Error while connecting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            if (isConnected) {
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                        .getOutputStream())), true); //create output stream to send data to server
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("remotedroid", "Error while creating OutWriter", e);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error while connecting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on the connect button my app is crashing and I don't know exactly why. Can you please help me?

Comment: The cause will be in the logcat. Have a look and post the relevant lines here.

Comment: `connectPhoneTask= new ConnectPhoneTask();` That statement should be in onClick();

Comment: `getByName(params[0]);` There is no `params[0]` as you called the task with `.execute();`. If you want to put something in `params[0]` then do it with `.execute(serverAddr)`;

Comment: `out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                        .getOutputStream())), true);`. That statement belongs in `doInBackground as internet code has to be done in a thread.`
          `

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I can connect now by using the Ip and a Port that I enter manually in a Connection Fragment. Now, when I connect to the server the Connection fragment is switching to the main activity and I would like to know how can I keep the socket connection ON?
I am trying to create a remote app, so I have a Mouse Fragment, Keyboard Fragment where  I will write the code for the operations but the connection should remain active when I will switch from the connection fragment to the other ones.. How can I do that? Does AsyncTask provides this function? Or should I use something different like a Service(I read something about the IBinder)

And the code looks like that in this moment :

```
Context context;
Button connectButton;
EditText IPAddress;
EditText PortTCP;
private boolean isConnected = false;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connect, container, false);

    context = this.getActivity();

    IPAddress = view.findViewById(R.id.IPAddress);
    PortTCP = view.findViewById(R.id.PortTCP);

    connectButton = view.findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
    connectButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ConnectPhoneTask connectPhoneTask = new ConnectPhoneTask(IPAddress.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(PortTCP.getText().toString()));
            connectPhoneTask.execute();
        }
    });

    return view;

}

public class ConnectPhoneTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    Socket socket;
    private Long startTime = 0l;
    private String TAG = "TCPClient";
    private String ipAddressInput;
    private int portTCPinput;


    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;


    ConnectPhoneTask(String ipAddress, int port) {

        ipAddressInput = ipAddress;
        portTCPinput = port;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.e("remotedroid", "Starting");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        boolean result = true;

        try {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ipAddressInput, portTCPinput));
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected! Current duration: " + time + "ms");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("remotedroid", "Conectarea nu s-a realizat!", e);
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        {
            isConnected = result;
            Toast.makeText(context, isConnected ? "Te-ai conectat cu succes la server!" : "Conectarea nu s-a realizat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                if (isConnected) {
                    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                            .getOutputStream())), true); //create output stream to send data to server
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("remotedroid", "Eroare la crearea OutWriter-ului", e);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Conecatarea nu s-a realizat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }



    }

}
```

}